# why are these 2 inline-blocks not aligning?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple case of checkbox-label to align and I can't seem to get it to work.
The label should wrap and all rows should start where the first row starts. 
Similar to this:

```
0 Xxxx
  xxxx
  xxxx
```

as opposed to this:

```
0 Xxxx
xxxxxx
xxxxxx
```

The html is:

```
<div class="limit">
    <input id="dd" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="dd" > Label text dh dfjgh dfhd;fhdh djh gfjh sfghj gpfhj sfpgdhj spfghj pfgohj spdfgoh spdfgih spdfgohi</label>
</div>
```

css:

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 1.5em;
    border: 1px dashed gray;
}

.limit {
  border: 1px solid black;
  vertical-align: top;
  max-width: 300px;
}

input {
  display: inline-block; 
}
```

and the live example is here: http://jsbin.com/virohima/1/edit?html,css,output

I'm getting this right now:

```
0 
  Xxxxx
  xxxxx
  xxxxx
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `float:left` to `input` and make `label` `display:block`

```
label {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 1.5em;
    border: 1px dashed gray;
}

.limit {
  border: 1px solid black;
  vertical-align: top;
  max-width: 300px;
}

input {
  display: inline-block; 
  float:left
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/virohima/5/)**

Comment: I like this answer because it doesn't make me put a `max-width` on the inline block. Also, I +1 @Suresh because he pointed out that an `inline-block` will take up 100% width and that was the root cause of the problem of my design. (This would make this answer complete, IMO)

Answer (score 1):

Assign width for inline elements otherwise it will take 100%.

```
 label {
 display: inline-block;
 border: 1px dashed gray;
 width:272px;
 }

.limit {
border: 1px solid black;
vertical-align: top;
max-width: 300px;
}

input {
display: inline-block; 
width:20px;
margin:0px;
vertical-align:top;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3XH4g/)

Comment: Thanks. I chose another answer but your comment helped me understand the problem in my design (I didn't choose your answer because I felt the better solution doesn't include `max-width` but I did +1 your answer)

Comment: no problem Ben. I am happy because it helps you somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
label {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 1.5em;
    border: 1px dashed gray;

}

.limit {
  border: 1px solid black;

  max-width: 300px;
}

input {
   float: left; 
}
```