# how to align sections vertically with display as inline-block

Tags: html, css

I was trying to recreate something like this example [Mozilla Comic-Strip Tutorial](https://thimble.mozilla.org/en-US/anonymous/48ad8595-9b65-4a41-bc4d-a34be99700b8/74), however my boxes would end up having different vertical alignments.

I looked around here and came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34421860/css-inline-block-wrap-issue-with-mixed-text-and-empty-div) and the solution worked fine for me. I am curious to know what is the difference between my case and the Mozilla's example.

Also, It would be nice to know why the two "infoSubPanel" div's are not vertically aligned as well.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24733610/why-are-these-2-inline-blocks-not-aligning) as well, but the first trick helped me.

P.P.S. for a part of this example I also looked into this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18221104/how-do-i-create-a-scrollable-textbox) as well.

I have pasted my code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>v0.01 Multi Section Page</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style>
            body {
               background-color: #efefef;
               font-family: sans-serif;
               text-align: left;
               padding: 20px 0 0 20px;
            }
            
            .mainScr {
               max-width: 1500px;
               margin: 1px;

            }
            
            .mainInfo {
                background-color: #D4FCD5;
                min-width: 495px;
                max-width: 1470px; 
                min-height: 100px;
                border: 1px double green;
            }

            .screenParts {
                vertical-align: top;
                width: 49%;
                max-width: 730px;
                min-width: 495px;
                min-height: 450px;
                border: 1px solid white;
                background: #F7E7C4;
                margin: 1px;
                display: inline-block;
            }
            
            .graphicsPanel {
                width: 100%;
                height: 66%;
                border: 1px solid blue;
                background: lightblue;
            }
          
            .dataPlots {
                width: 100%;
                height: 33%;
                border: 1px solid brown;
                background: beige;
            }
            
            .infoSubPanel {
                min-height:450px;
                width:48%;
                min-width: 250;
                display:inline-flex;
                border: 1px solid brown;
            }
            .scrollabletextbox {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                min-height: 500px;
                font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size: 100%;
                overflow:scroll;
                resize: none;
                text-align: left;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
      
    <body>
        <div class="mainInfo">
            <h1>Very important data goes here...</h1>
        </div>        
        <div class="mainScr">     
            <div id="visual" class="screenParts">
                <div class="graphicsPanel">
                    <h1>Some Graphics Goes Here</h1>
                    <h1>Some Graphics Goes Here</h1>
                    <h1>Some Graphics Goes Here</h1>
                    <h1>Some Graphics Goes Here</h1>
                    <h1>Some Graphics Goes Here</h1>
                </div>
                
                <div class="dataPlots">
                    <div style="display: block;">
                        <p> charts and plots go here</p>
                        <p> charts and plots go here</p>
                        <p> charts and plots go here</p>
                        <p> charts and plots go here</p>
                        <p> charts and plots go here</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="detail" class="screenParts">
                <div class="infoSubPanel">
                    <div style="display: block;">
                        <p>Some info and date-time will go here...</p>
                        <p>Some info and date-time will go here...</p>
                        <p>Some info and date-time will go here...</p>
                        <p>Some info and date-time will go here...</p>
                        <p>Some info and date-time will go here....</p>
                        <p>Some info and date-time will go here...</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="infoSubPanel">
                    <textarea class="scrollabletextbox" name="logs">
blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah                        
                    </textarea>
                </div>
            </div>        
        
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I looked around here and came across this question and the solution
>   worked fine for me. I am curious to know what is the difference
>   between my case and the Mozilla's example.

- **This is an off-topic question for SO.**

> Also, It would be nice to know why the two `infoSubPanel` div's are
>   not vertically aligned as well.

- you are using `inline-flex` which is an inline element like `inline-block` which by default have `vertical-align:baseline`, set it `vertical-align:top`

---

```css
body {
  background-color: #efefef;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 20px 0 0 20px;
}
.mainScr {
  max-width: 1500px;
  margin: 1px;
}
.mainInfo {
  background-color: #D4FCD5;
  min-width: 495px;
  max-width: 1470px;
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px double green;
}
.screenParts {
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 49%;
  max-width: 730px;
  min-width: 495px;
  min-height: 450px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: #F7E7C4;
  margin: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.graphicsPanel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 66%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: lightblue;
}
.dataPlots {
  width: 100%;
  height: 33%;
  border: 1px solid brown;
  background: beige;
}
.infoSubPanel {
  min-height: 450px;
  width: 48%;
  min-width: 250;
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid brown;
  vertical-align:top
}
.scrollabletextbox {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
  font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
  resize: none;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainInfo">
  <h1>Very important data goes here...</h1>
</div>
<div class="mainScr">
  <div id="visual" class="screenParts">
    <div class="graphicsPanel">
      <h1>Some Graphics Goes Here</h1>
      <h1>Some Graphics Goes Here</h1>
      <h1>Some Graphics Goes Here</h1>
      <h1>Some Graphics Goes Here</h1>
      <h1>Some Graphics Goes Here</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="dataPlots">
      <div style="display: block;">
        <p>charts and plots go here</p>
        <p>charts and plots go here</p>
        <p>charts and plots go here</p>
        <p>charts and plots go here</p>
        <p>charts and plots go here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="detail" class="screenParts">
    <div class="infoSubPanel">
      <div style="display: block;">
        <p>Some info and date-time will go here...</p>
        <p>Some info and date-time will go here...</p>
        <p>Some info and date-time will go here...</p>
        <p>Some info and date-time will go here...</p>
        <p>Some info and date-time will go here....</p>
        <p>Some info and date-time will go here...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="infoSubPanel">
      <textarea class="scrollabletextbox" name="logs">
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
      </textarea>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @dippas, vertical aligned fixed the second issue. so is this the same problem for the first part as well?

Comment: @fetah what 1st part are you talking about?

Comment: thanks for following up. I meant why the Mozilla example does not need vertical align but I need them? there should be a detail that Im missing. Thanks

Comment: @fetah I'm using Firefox and I need as well. it is explained in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think u only need add this changes in your css.

```
.infoSubPanel{
float:left
}
.scrollabletextbox {       
/* height: 100%; */remove this
/* min-height: 500px; */remove this
float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I prefer not to use float and avoid it because I still dont know how it exactly works and some times it throws my divs out their parent divs.

Answer (score 0):

To vertically-align inline-block elements simply style each element with `vertical-align: top;`

Comment: Thanks I know vertical-align fixed it but Im wondering why. In the example, they did not use it.